# C++ передача класса как параметра

Tags: c++, классы, полиморфизм, параметры

Имеется родительский класс **GamePiece**, от него наследуется фигура **Pawn**.

```
class GamePiece
{
public:
    GamePiece(char PieceColor) : mPieceColor(PieceColor) {}

    virtual char GetPiece() = 0;
    char GetColor() {
        return mPieceColor;
    }
    
private:
    virtual bool // поведение фигуры
    const char mPieceColor;
};


class PawnPiece : public GamePiece
{
public:
    PawnPiece(char PieceColor) : GamePiece(PieceColor) {}
private:
    char GetPiece() override{
        return 'P';
    }
    {
    /* Поведение фигуры */
    }
};
```

Также имеется GamePiece игровая доска, на которой мои пешки будут стоять. Моя цель - реализовать функцию установки пешки на доску. Пока что у меня получилась плохая на мой взгляд функция,работающая только для одной фигуры.

```
class CBoard
{
public:
    GamePiece* GameBoard[8][8];

void SetPawnPiece(int iRow, int iCol, char PieceColor) {
    GameBoard[iRow][iCol] = new PawnPiece(PieceColor);
}
...
```

Как написать универсальную функцию, фигуру которой я могу передавать как параметр, или с которой будет удобнее работать на Ваш взгляд?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите сделать одну функцию, которая будет устанавливать любую фигуру на определённую клетку?

Comment: Вы говорите об "установке пешки на доску", т.е. одной фигуры. Чем же плоха эта функция?

Comment: @nyekitka Да, фигуру задаем как любой другой параметр

Comment: @Mikhailo для новой фигуры, король, например, придется писать новую функцию. На мой взгляд это не самое оптимальное решение

Comment: Можно просто наследовать класс фигуры и делать пешки, ладьи и т.д., и функции достаточно будет одной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужна функция, куда передается класс фигуры, который нужно положить на доску, и она внутри себя единообразно создает фигуру и добавляет в соответствующую клетку, то видимо вам нужен шаблон:

```
class CBoard
{
public:
    GamePiece* GameBoard[8][8];

template <typename T>
void SetPiece(int iRow, int iCol, char PieceColor) {
    GameBoard[iRow][iCol] = new T(PieceColor);
}
```

Использование:

```
CBoard board;
board.SetPiece<PawnPiece>(1, 0, 'W')
```

Обратите внимание, что все ваши фигуры должны иметь конструктор, принимающий `char` в качестве параметра

---

upd

Также обратите внимание на очень вероятную утечку памяти если несколько раз поместить фигуру в одну и ту же клетку. На дворе 2022 год, рекомендую воспользоваться умными указателями

Comment: Для иерархии классов смешивать шаблон есть очень плохая идея, если вы понимаете когда и для чего используется наследование. После многократного вызова функции члена как собираетесь бороться  с утечкой памяти?...

Comment: Чем же? Если мы передадим в качестве шаблонного аргумента класс, лежащий вне иерархии наследования, компилятор обматерит нас при попытке записать созданный указатель в доску. Каноничное же решение с использованием динамического полиморфизма подразумевает создание фабрики, куда передается название фигуры и ее цвет, а возвращается созданный указатель. Это более громоздко и в данном примере на мой взгляд излишне. Впрочем я готов подискутировать на эту тему

Comment: На счет утечек памяти это совершенно отдельный вопрос, я думал обратить на это внимание при  написании ответа, но передумал, так как оригинальная функция автора имеет ровно ту же проблему. Хороший вариант - умные указатели. Вариант похуже - проверять ручками перед установкой фигуры, есть ли что-то в клетке (предварительно проинициализировав ее `nullptr`-ами и чистить. Но это, имхо, имеет слабое отношение к теме вопроса

Comment: Добавил ремарку про память